# watching variable values in Code Composer

Tags: c, code-composer

I work in **Code Composer Studio Version: 6.0.1.00040** 
with the card **LCDK C6748**, but I think this is a more general question, relating to CCS generally.
I'm trying to implement LMS for cancelling acoustic echoes,
this is the skeleton of my .c file:

```
void waitForInterrupt()
{
   while (flag==0) {}

     flag=0; // reach this line only when flag == 1
}

interrupt void interrupt4(void)
{
    // Inputs
    inputRight_micSignal = (float)input_right_sample();

    // Outputs
    outputLeft_referenceSignal= whiteNoiseSample;
    codec_data.channel[RIGHT]= (uint16_t)outputRight_cleanedSound;
    codec_data.channel[LEFT]= (uint16_t)outputLeft_referenceSignal;
    output_sample(codec_data.uint);

    flag = 1;
}

void main()
{
    // variables decelerations
    int i;
    float filter_output;

    // initialising filter coefficients
    for (i=0 ; i<ADAPTIVE_FILT_SIZE ; i++) // initialise weights and delay line
    {
        w[i] = 0.0;
        x[i] = 0.0;
    }

    // initialising the interrupt routine
    L138_initialise_intr(FS_8000_HZ,ADC_GAIN_0DB,DAC_ATTEN_0DB,LCDK_MIC_INPUT);

    while(1)        // adaptive filtering routine
    {
        waitForInterrupt();

        whiteNoiseSample = getPrnFiltered();

        for (i = ADAPTIVE_FILT_SIZE-1; i > 0; i--) // update delay line - TDL:merge later with w loop (still make sure no magic NaN's appear)
        {
            x[i] = x[i-1];
        }
        x[0] = outputLeft_referenceSignal;        // input to adaptive filter

        filter_output = 0;                      //reseting filter output
        // compute adaptive filter output
        for (i = 0; i < ADAPTIVE_FILT_SIZE; i++)
            filter_output += (w[i]*x[i]);

        outputRight_cleanedSound = inputRight_micSignal - filter_output; // compute error

        for (i = ADAPTIVE_FILT_SIZE-1; i >= 0; i--) // update weights and delay line
        {
            w[i] = w[i] + beta*outputRight_cleanedSound*x[i]; // w[i]+=beta*"error"*"reference"
        }
```

from some reason when I put the arrays `x[]` and `w[]` in the "watch table"
and I suspend the running of the program (in order to examine w[] coefficients after awhile, I see that it is full of NaN's - while x[] contains "regular"
values. 
when I put breakpoint inside the line where w[] is calculated:

```
            w[i] = w[i] + beta*outputRight_cleanedSound*x[i]; // w[i]+=beta*"error"*"reference"
```

I see the flow goes there.
What could be the reason for the NaN's?
Is there a way to watch w[] in the "wach table"?

Answer (score 1):

These three steps work for me:

1) First you need to make sure the variables are globally available (e.g. that they are not allocated on the stack).

2) You need to halt the processor before trying to read the variables. (In Debug view: Tools -> Debugger Options -> Auto Run and Launch Options).

3) Enable "halt the target before any debugger access" on the watch window and click the "auto-update" icon in the "Variables"-window.

I've uploaded a screenshot with red boxes around the stuff you need to touch.
See if that helps you :) Otherwise check out TI's Engineer2Engineer forum (E2E). In my experience the TI guys are quick to answer and I've gotten very competent help from them.

Tell me how it works for you :) ?

FWIW I'm using Code Composer Studio v.5.5.0.00077.

[image]

Comment: @Day_Dreamer If you break the code manually, can you watch the variable then? If not, it won't auto-update its value either.